# AngularJS and Spring MVC integration

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I am facing a peculiar issue while incorporating angularjs as front end for spring boot mvc project. I cant figure out the root cause of why this is happening. My angularjs template and angular controller codes are listed below.As long as I have angularjs script/controller within 'script' tags of the template file the code works fine and I get the desired result.However as soon as I create a seperate javascript file for the controller in resource/static/app folder of Spring Boot project directory and import using src(as shown below) then the angularjs stops working. Would be great if someone can help me understand why is this happening. Is there some other configuration that needs to be done for importing javascript file in Spring boot templates?

**1. spring boot html template file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>Spring MVC+Angular</title>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/app/controller.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/app/controller.js"></script>

<!--  <script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller("mycontroller" , function($scope){
                $scope.name = "myapp controller456...."  ;    
});

</script>-->

</head>

<body>
<div>
<div data-ng-controller="mycontroller" >
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here123456..."></input></p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. angularjs controller**

```
// please note that the same controller when included within script tag of template file works however if included as separate javascript file does not work//

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller("mycontroller" , function($scope){
                $scope.name = "myapp controller456...."  ;    
});
```

Comment: Have you checked that the http request for the js-script file does "download" the file but not ends with 404-not found?

Comment: Would be great if you can suggest some method to check on that?I am more or less a newbie. In case you want to ascertain whether contoller file is being detected in the template or not then for your information Spring Tool Suite is able to resolve both "myapp" and "mycontroller" variables in the template file.

Comment: Firefox F12 network console, or Firebug Network console for example.

Comment: Yes you are spot on Chrome developer console displays following message : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) i.e. following link is not accessible: http://localhost:8181/static/app/controller.js . I tried few trial and error combinations of static folder and corresponding folder resource path. But none of them seem to be working.

Comment: If you have stored the resources in `src/main/resources/static/app/..` remove the folder `static` from the urls. The contents of the folder `src/main/resources/static/` are automatically mapped by Spring Boot to the root context in your app.

Comment: Thanks , if i change from "src="../static/app/controller.js" " to "src="/app/controller.js"" then it works , but is this not a logically incorrect URL because Spring Tool Suite also displays an error "undefined javascript file" , however it works well on the browser as expected.Would  be great if you can provide some explanation for this.